# Equivalent function of MatLab's "dateshift(...)" in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, date

MatLab can take a date and move it to the end of the month, quarter, etc. using the `dateshift(...)` [function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dateshift.html).

Is there an equivalent function in Python?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it counts as the same, but the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module can make times available as a [`timetuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.timetuple), with separate components for year, month, day etc. This is easy to manipulate directly to advance to the next month, etc.

If you don't mind using an extension, check out [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). The list of features starts with:

> - Computing of relative deltas (next month, next year, next monday, last week of month, etc);

The documentation for [`dateutil.relativedelta`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#relativedelta-examples) shows how to advance to various points.

Answer (score 0):

I think `calendar.monthrange` should do it for you, e.g.:

```
>>> import datetime, calendar
>>> year = int(input("Enter year: "))
Enter year: 2012
>>> month = int(input("Enter month: "))
Enter month: 3
>>> endOfMonthDate = datetime.date(year, month, calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1])
>>> endOfMonthDate
datetime.date(2012, 3, 31)
>>>
```

You might find other helpful functions here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html and here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html